# Different printing options for one network printer

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

We got a Canon MF6180dw multifunctional printer at the office. It is connected to the network through a LAN cable. Everything is working properly, but we don't want to change the printing options every time we need to print something (The printer has 3 source it can print from, 2 drawers and 1 multi-purpose tray). We would need 3 fixed configuration for printing, one for simple A4 printing (drawer 2), one for printing letters (drawer 1) and the multi-purpose would print a specific size we need.

First, I though we would set up a same printer driver (UFRII LT) three times, with different settings, but I would need to add and configure these printers on every computer that is on the network and even than, the users can misconfigure them.

How can I setup a single printer's configuration "shortcuts" so I won't need to make changes on every computer?

The image below shows what I tried to setup, a copy would print from another drawer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the users connect directly to the printer, then yes, you need to install all 3 of them on every PC. However, if you install the drivers on a server, your problems go away. Install the printer on the server 3 times, and set the defaults for each copy from Printer Properties > Advanced tab > Printing Defaults.

Then the users can install those drivers by connecting to the server. To make it even easier for them, the printers can be installed via a login script or GPO.

Comment: I wanted to try this at first, but then I can't send the scanned documents to a certain computer on the network from the printer. (When I start a batch scanning on the printer, I can select which computer to send it to and it automatically saves the scanned document in the pre-set format).

Comment: Scanning is a different issue from printing. I do not know of a simple way to propagate a scanner driver. Can you set the printer itself up so it "knows" the different computers? That way, each user just has to select the PC to scan to, at the printer itself.

Comment: According to the e-manual at http://usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/black_white_laser_multifunction/imageclass_mf6180dw#BrochuresAndManuals it is possible to set the printer up so the users can select their PC/folder from the printer's menu when they scan. If the printrer is network-connected, up to 10 PCs can be used that way.

Comment: Yes, and If I only install it to the server, this function won't work anymore, because the only computer will be selectable on the printer is the server.

Comment: In the e-manual, under "How to Save to a File Server (A Shared File Server)" it shows how to set it up. You should specify a different Speed Dial number for each PC. Under "Specifying the Destination (File Server)" it shows how to select the PCs at scan time, using Speed Dial.